# How to get iPad screen size in different orientations?

Tags: ios, xcode

I am writing my first iPad application. One of the very first problems i ran into is the screen size in different orientations.

When i try using these two:

```
view.frame
```

or

```
view.bounds
```

I get the screen resolutions for the portrait mode. Note that i need both the large and mini iPad screen size. I have also tried using mainScreen but i get the same results as the above codes.

Comment: Is the screen orientation actually changing? That is, does `willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:duration:` get called with the correct orientation when rotating the device?

Answer (score 0):

Here you go

```
- (void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation 
{
    CGFloat width = CGRectGetWidth(self.view.bounds);
}
```

Comment: it works but im not sure if the result is correct. i get 1024 in landscape and 768 in portrait. But when i change to ipad retina i get the same results. isnt it supposed to return 2048 for retina display?

Comment: I think you're using a simulator. Close, clean and rebuild on retina and it will return 2048!